# How to manage multiple versions of an internal library in a cmake-based project?

Tags: c++, cmake, project, dependency-management

I have a question regarding CMake-based projects with shared internal libraries.

I currently have the following codebase:

```
RootFolder
   
    CMakeLists.txt
    
    Lib1
    |- lib1.cpp
    |- lib1.h
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    
    App1
    |- app1.cpp
    |- app1.h
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    
    App2
    |- app2.cpp
    |- app2.h
    |- CMakeLists.txt
```

Both App1 and App2 need to link against Lib1.
I was able to set up my CMakeLists files to make it work in a case where both App1 and App2 can link against the same version of Lib1.

However, here is the case I cannot resolve:
Say I make some breaking changes to the Lib1 interface, which implies that App1 and App2 need to be modified in order to compile.
However, for some reason, I can only update App1 according to Lib1 updates.

But say, I also need to modify App2, while keeping the previous Lib1 version.

How can I manage this situation?

Comment: If you make a "breaking" change to `Lib1` that, by definition of a "breaking" change, breaks both `App1` and `App2`, then it seems pretty clear that `App1` and `App2` both need changing. If your statement "However, for some reason, I can only update App1 according to Lib1 updates." *really* means "some management, political, or whimsical mandate prevents me from updating `App2`" , then your only choice seems a fork and separate lib. I'll admit, after reading this twice, I don't have a clue what you're trying to do, so I'll wait patiently for someone that has better decipherment skills.

Comment: In some cases it may be possible to keep both the old functionality and the new one by using different namespaces and provide one as the default one, but there's far to little info about the library, the interface and the nature of the changes for this question to be answerable with an answer of reasonable length.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hello! Thanks for the comment. What prevents me from updating App2 to align it with the last Lib1 is indeed management-related (we can obviously consider this is a Bad Idea, but you know, managers ...). Sorry if i was not clear! I was just thinking about thé best way to manage multiple version of thé same lib in my cmake project

Comment: I see plenty of ways, but from your question, I can't guess what is possible for you and what is not. As for me, I would split this repo into 3 independent projects w/ their own release cycle, so each app could use whatever version of independently released Lib1.